# perl cannot `exec` to binary

Tags: perl, exec

In my fresh installation of Debin, perl intepreter is installed by default (in other words, I have no other perl packages yet). However, trying this:

```
$ls
a.cpp b.cpp
$ perl -e 'system "g++ -o a.out a.cpp b.cpp"; exec "a.out"'
```

gives no output (no error, nothing). The perl properly used the `system` command (that is - it created the `a.out` executable), but cannot fork to it. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the [documentation of `exec`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#exec-LIST) but it's hard to see if you don't know what you're looking for.

> If there is more than one argument in LIST, this calls execv**p**(3) with the arguments in LIST. If there is only one element in LIST, the argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and if there are any, the entire argument is passed to the system's command shell for parsing (…). If there are no shell metacharacters in the argument, it is split into words and passed directly to execv**p** (…).

In all cases, the command name is subject to path lookup (either by Perl or by the shell): if it doesn't contain a `/`, it's looked up in the command search path (`$PATH`), which usually doesn't contain the current directory.

Change to

```
exec "./a.out"
```

Answer (score 1):

> ...  but cannot fork to it

`exec` does not fork at all but replaces the currently running application code (i.e. perl) with a new one (a.out).

Apart from that, it is unclear what output is even expected from `a.out`, i.e. the problem might be `a.out` and not perl.

It might also be that the system simply does not look for `a.out` in the local directory for the binary, since the `PATH` environment variable does not explicitly include `.` . To force execution do `exec "./a.out"` instead.

Comment: `exec` _tries to_ replace it. If `a.out` isn't in `PATH`, `exec` will return an error instead. Check the error to see if the issue is that the exec doesn't work, or that the launched progrma does't work. `perl -e 'exec "a.out" or die "exec: $!"'`.